# How can I iteratively create multiple tibbles using a function in R (tidyverse)?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have to create 10 tibbles with identical variables (data just differs), this leads to me duplicating the following code

```r
dpd <- list_sheets[[1]] %>%
    filter(LASTUSER %in% users ) %>% 
    mutate(year = as.numeric(format(DATEMODIFI, format = "%Y")),
           month = as.numeric(format(DATEMODIFI, format = "%m")),
           day = as.numeric(format(DATEMODIFI, format = "%d"))) %>% 
    select(-DATEMODIFI) %>% 
    filter(year == 2019),

  fuse <- list_sheets[[2]]%>%
    filter(LASTUSER %in% users ) %>% 
    mutate(year = as.numeric(format(DATEMODIFI, format = "%Y")),
           month = as.numeric(format(DATEMODIFI, format = "%m")),
           day = as.numeric(format(DATEMODIFI, format = "%d"))) %>% 
    select(-DATEMODIFI) %>% 
    filter(year == 2019),

  ohprimary <- list_sheets[[3]]%>%
    filter(LASTUSER %in% users ) %>% 
    mutate(year = as.numeric(format(DATEMODIFI, format = "%Y")),
           month = as.numeric(format(DATEMODIFI, format = "%m")),
           day = as.numeric(format(DATEMODIFI, format = "%d"))) %>% 
    select(-DATEMODIFI) %>% 
    filter(year == 2019),

  ohsecondary <- list_sheets[[4]]%>%
    filter(LASTUSER %in% users ) %>% 
    mutate(year = as.numeric(format(DATEMODIFI, format = "%Y")),
           month = as.numeric(format(DATEMODIFI, format = "%m")),
           day = as.numeric(format(DATEMODIFI, format = "%d"))) %>% 
    select(-DATEMODIFI) %>% 
    filter(year == 2019),

  poles <- list_sheets[[5]]%>%
    filter(LASTUSER %in% users ) %>% 
    mutate(year = as.numeric(format(DATEMODIFI, format = "%Y")),
           month = as.numeric(format(DATEMODIFI, format = "%m")),
           day = as.numeric(format(DATEMODIFI, format = "%d"))) %>% 
    select(-DATEMODIFI) %>% 
    filter(year == 2019),

  pv <- list_sheets[[6]]%>%
    filter(LASTUSER %in% users ) %>% 
    mutate(year = as.numeric(format(DATEMODIFI, format = "%Y")),
           month = as.numeric(format(DATEMODIFI, format = "%m")),
           day = as.numeric(format(DATEMODIFI, format = "%d"))) %>% 
    select(-DATEMODIFI) %>% 
    filter(year == 2019),

  switch <- list_sheets[[7]]%>%
    filter(LASTUSER %in% users ) %>% 
    mutate(year = as.numeric(format(DATEMODIFI, format = "%Y")),
           month = as.numeric(format(DATEMODIFI, format = "%m")),
           day = as.numeric(format(DATEMODIFI, format = "%d")))%>% 
    select(-DATEMODIFI) %>% 
    filter(year == 2019),

  transformers <- list_sheets[[8]]%>%
    filter(LASTUSER %in% users ) %>% 
    mutate(year = as.numeric(format(DATEMODIFI, format = "%Y")),
           month = as.numeric(format(DATEMODIFI, format = "%m")),
           day = as.numeric(format(DATEMODIFI, format = "%d")))%>% 
    select(-DATEMODIFI) %>% 
    filter(year == 2019),

  ugprimary <- list_sheets[[9]]%>%
    filter(LASTUSER %in% users ) %>% 
    mutate(year = as.numeric(format(DATEMODIFI, format = "%Y")),
           month = as.numeric(format(DATEMODIFI, format = "%m")),
           day = as.numeric(format(DATEMODIFI, format = "%d")))%>% 
    select(-DATEMODIFI) %>% 
    filter(year == 2019),

  ugsecondary <- list_sheets[[10]]%>%
    filter(LASTUSER %in% users ) %>% 
    mutate(year = as.numeric(format(DATEMODIFI, format = "%Y")),
           month = as.numeric(format(DATEMODIFI, format = "%m")),
           day = as.numeric(format(DATEMODIFI, format = "%d")))%>% 
    select(-DATEMODIFI) %>% 
    filter(year == 2019)
```

So I created the following function, and tried to create them iteratively like so:

```r
createTibble <- function(i){
  list_sheets[[i]]%>%
    filter(LASTUSER %in% users ) %>% 
    mutate(year = as.numeric(format(DATEMODIFI, format = "%Y")),
           month = as.numeric(format(DATEMODIFI, format = "%m")),
           day = as.numeric(format(DATEMODIFI, format = "%d")))%>% 
    select(-DATEMODIFI) %>% 
    filter(year == 2019)


}

features <- c('dpd', 'fuse')

for (feature in seq_along(features)){
  tibble <- sym(features[feature]) # returns the proper symbol e.g. 'dpd' -> dpd 
  tibble <- createTibble(feature) # This just gives me a table called tibble

}
```

This will not give me two tibbles (dpd and fuse) instead I'll just get a tibble called tibble

What am I doing wrong? I love R but why does it have to be soooo annoying to do stuff like this

edit:

```r
features <- c('dpd', 'fuse')
output <- vector('list', length(features))
for (feature in seq_along(features)){

  output[[feature]] <- createTibble(feature)
  name <- sym(features[feature])
  print(name)
  name <- output[[feature]]

}
```

Comment: You need to create a list to store the output i.e. `out <- vector('list', length(features))` and within the `for` loop, `out[[feature]] <- createTibble(feature)` `tibble` is a function name, please use different name as an object name

Comment: Okay I am misunderstanding you because this gives the same exact result, please see my edit.

Comment: I don't see any edit and what do you meant by `same exact result` (is it the one from `for` loop?)  Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: check again, sorry. I mean to say that it doesn't return two different tibbles with the correct name, just a single tibble with the name of the variable I used

Comment: If you have assigned `output[[feature]] <- createTibble(feature)` and your `createTibble` works, then it should return two elements in `output` because you already created `output <- vector('list', length(features))` check the `output`  If you are checking `name`, it wouldn't be the case.  Also, you may need to assign the names of 'output' as `names(output) <- features` after the `for` loop i.e. no need for `name <- sym(features[feature])`

Comment: right and it does, but that's not the issue. The point is that two individual tibbles be returned, not a list of them. Is this not possible? i.e. return the individual elements of the list from the loop as to not need to duplicate the same line ten times

Comment: I wouldn't recommend creating multiple objects in the global env

Comment: you never have multiple tables in your environment?

Comment: ...Okay I don't think we are talking about the same thing here. How is there never a scenario for which you have had multiple tables loaded in your environment? Also this is not the answer to my question... I did not ask how to create a list of objects

Comment: I posted as a solution with the requirements you want

Comment: @akrun Thank you, can you provide a source on why I wouldn't want two or more tables like that in my global env? I have never heard that before and have gone through a few guides on R

Comment: Simple reason is that you may require to do more transformation on the same objects, then you have to do the same loading, assign etc and write to csv.  Instead, this can be done more easily in a `list`

Comment: ah okay I see what you're saying, thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create a `list` of objects, initialize with an empty `list` and assign the value to it based on the output of the function in each iteration of `for` loop

```
features <- c('dpd', 'fuse')
output <- setNames(vector('list', length(features)), features)
for (feature in seq_along(features)){

   output[[feature]] <- createTibble(feature)
}
```

It is not recommended to have multiple objects in the global environment, but if that is required, an option is `assign`

```
for (feature in seq_along(features)){
    assign(features[feature], value = createTibble(feature))
 }
```

Now, we check

```
ls()
```

for the objects that are created

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(purrr)
map(seq_along(features), ~createTibble(.x)) %>%
   set_names(features) %>%
   list2env(.GlobalEnv)
```